# Prove that a sub-sigma-algebra is sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following exercise.

> Let $(X,\mathbb{E})$ be a measurable space and $\widetilde{X}\subseteq X$, $X\ne\emptyset$. A sub-$\sigma$-algebra is defined by: 
>   \begin{equation*}
>     \mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}=\{\widetilde{X}\cap E\ |\ E\in\mathbb{E}\}
> \end{equation*}
>   Prove that $\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra in $\widetilde{X}$. Prove that $\widetilde{X}\in\mathbb{E}$ if and only if $\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}\subseteq\mathbb{E}$.

*Proof that $\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra:*

$\widetilde{X}\subseteq X$ implies that $\widetilde{X}=\widetilde{X}\cap X\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$, since $X\in\mathbb{E}$

If $A_{i}\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$, then $\widetilde{X}-A_{i}=\widetilde{X}\cap X - \widetilde{X}\cap E_{i}=\widetilde{X}\cap(X-E_{i})=\widetilde{X}\cap E_{i}^{c}\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$, since $E_{i}^{c}\in\mathbb{E}$, for some $E_{i}\in\mathbb{E}$.

$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\widetilde{X}\cap E_{n}=\widetilde{X}\cap\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}E_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$, since $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}E_{n}\in\mathbb{E}$, when $A_{n}\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$ for $n=1,2,...$

*Proof that $\widetilde{X}\in\mathbb{E}$ implies $\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}\subseteq\mathbb{E}$:*

Shouldn't this just be, take $A\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}\implies A=\widetilde{X}\cap E\in\mathbb{E}$, since $E\in\mathbb{E}$? Why do I need to know that $\widetilde{X}\in\mathbb{E}$?

*Proof that $\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}\subseteq\mathbb{E}$ implies $\widetilde{X}\in\mathbb{E}$:*

Suppose $\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}\subseteq\mathbb{E}$, that is every element $A\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$ is also an element of $\mathbb{E}$. Hence, $\widetilde{X}\in\mathbb{E}_{\widetilde{X}}$ implies $\widetilde{X}\in\mathbb{E}$.

Comment: It seems to me that $\mathbb E_{\widetilde X}$ defined like that is *automatically* a $\sigma$-algebra on $\widetilde X$. For that we do not need $\mathbb E_{\widetilde X}\subseteq\mathbb E$. E.g. let $\mathbb E=\{\varnothing,X\}$. Then $\mathbb E_{\widetilde X}=\{\varnothing,\widetilde X\}$.

Comment: You are correct, I requested feedback and just been informed that the exercise was not properly phrased. I have updated now.

Answer (score 2):

That is false.
We took $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{E}=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R}\}$.

We took $\widetilde X=\mathbb{Q}$ then $\mathbb{E}_{\mathbb{Q}}=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{Q}\}$ but $\mathbb{Q} \not\in \mathbb{E}$.